# User not disconnecting in Socket.IO Node.Js app ONLY on https connection - caching issue?

Tags: node.js, sockets, caching, https, socket.io

I'm having this issue with my Socket.Io / Node.Js app that when I reload a page Socket.IO still thinks that the "previous" me is connected to the chat room, so it thinks there's two people in the chat room instead of one. After a while (maybe like a minute) this problem disappears.

I tried resolving it but I think there's some issue with cache - that even though I reload the browser window the previous session is still active, so it "thinks" two people are connected.

This issue doesn't occur at all times, but always on HTTPS connection, and almost always on iOS and sometimes in Safari / Chrome and other browsers (on all systems with https connection).

**Do you know what the issue might really be and what would be the best way to resolve it?**

I use all the standard code for setting up the Socket.IO connection and the app is running on Express / Node.Js.

I can put the code here, but it's quite a lot, the open source code is available on http://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus (the `app.js` file and `public/entries.js` is where the socket.io code is).

Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering, do you always get `emit('leave' ?

Comment: on my local machine - yes. when i use it with https on a remote server - no. i think there's a problem with caching, like the browser still keeps the old session while loading the new one. i don't know why but would be good to have a workaround for that....